# (pug template) TypeError: require is not a function

Tags: webpack, pug

Here's my code:

```
img(src=require('/images/menu/img.svg'))
```

I need the image to be in dist folder using webpack.

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loaders: ['html-loader?attrs=img:src',
      'pug-html-loader?{"pretty":true,"exports":false}'
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
    use: [{
      loader: "file-loader",
      options:{
        name:'[path][hash].[name].[ext]'
      }
    }]        
  }
```

But I always got this error. Please help. Do I need to install a loader or any dependecies?

```
TypeError: require is not a function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. For a start you have a different number of opening and closing brackets for `img(()`.

Comment: Hi @MikePoole, yeah sorry about that, forgot to copy the last ")". Still not the issue though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `require()`? Have you tried just `img(src='/images/menu/img.svg')`?

Comment: Hi @sean, Already tried that but I need to include the image in webpack and save it to the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the plugin [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin).

Install:

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

And add this to your webpack config:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '/PATH-TO/images/menu/img.svg'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist/images/menu/img.svg')
      },
    ]),
  ],
  // ...
};
```